Permission denied: AH00529: /home/username/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
I'm seeing a lot of errors in apache error log:

(13)Permission denied: [client xyz:63932] AH00529:
/home/username/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check
htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that
'/home/username/public_html/' is executable  Default permissions for
all account's public_html is 711 and for .htaccess 644.

The owner and group both are set to be respective account's username. I need this one so I don't want to change owners and groups.
I've been reading  various threads and it is confusing. In some thread they say it should be 755 while on others they say to set it 751 (default for cPanel).
What should be default permissions for public_html folders?

What's kinda PHP application causing this error message? A Wordpress site? According to this error message you'd set public_html directory to 711 and the .htaccess to 644. Did you already try to do that?

I've mostly php apps, WordPress, Yii and these are the ones causing above issues. I didn't change any permissions on any folder. My server has cPanel so all the permissions are set by cPanel during account creation. Forgot to say, yes the permissions are already set correctly to "public_html directory to 711 and the .htaccess to 644"

Does this issue occur with all the PHP applications or only some?

@JorgeLuiz it seems to occur with mostly all of the apps. I found that cPanel sets the default permissions for public_html folder to 0750 as per this thread AH00529: /home/datemantra/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/datemantra/public_html/' is executable
it seems to be intended behaviour dictated by cPanel?

What's your hosting service? Did you tryed to reach out to its support team?

@JorgeLuiz It is dedicated server, I'm managing it. I've posted it on cPanel but they are yet to respond.


Check Permissions
Make sure the public_html directory and the .htaccess file have the right permissions.

For the public_html directory:
chmod 711 /home/username/public_html
This lets the owner read, write, and execute, while others can execute.
For the .htaccess file:
chmod 644 /home/username/public_html/.htaccess
This lets the owner read and write, while others can only read.

Check Ownership
Make sure the right user (the web server user) owns the public_html directory and the .htaccess file.

Run this command to set ownership:
chown username:username /home/username/public_html/.htaccess
chown username:username /home/username/public_html
Replace username with your account's username.

Verify Parent Directory Permissions
Make sure all parent directories leading to public_html are executable (permission x) by the web server user.

For example:
chmod 711 /home/username
4. Look Over Your .htaccess File for Grammar Mistakes
If the permissions and ownership are right, the .htaccess file might have grammar errors. Take a close look at what's inside to spot any slip-ups.

You didn't read the question and discussion in the comments. It is cPanel's settings which may revert the permissions even if I change it manually.
